# unable to download ipa in iphone 6 on version ios 8.3

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I got an serious issue running IPA on iPhone 5s with iOS 8.3 is working           fine but trying to download the same IPA on iPhone 6 with iOS 8.3 gives error unable to download.

I tried a lot but got same issue. Number of times creating provisioning profiles added `UDID's` but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the new Xcode 6.3 does not replaces the new profile downloaded from Apple Developer account.

Can you try following steps:

1. Rename your .ipa file to .zip
2. Unzip this file
3. You will find `Payload` folder
4. Inside `Payload` folder there will be `YourAppName.app` file
5. Right click on it and `Show package content`
6. Inside there should be file `embedded.mobileprovision`
7. Open this file by right clicking and open with TextEdit
8. In that file either search for that UDID, if you can find then that UDID is attached in that profile else not. Usually all UDID attached in profile are present in:

   ```
   <key>ProvisionedDevices</key>
       <array>
   ```

If that device UDID is not present either you can delete that profile from Xcode or rename profile name before downloading from Apple Developer Account

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, let me try this and then let to know....thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Check in your **Build Settings**  for **Code Signing** and change development -> Distribution.